# Convert js function to C#

Tags: c#

I wanna convert the below js to C#:

js:

```
 "pet":{
    "animal":"cat",
    "food": function(val) {
         return (
           'X: ' +  val.data.value[0]
         );
    },
  },`
```

I have prepared part of the C#, but not sure how to make the js food function part, any idea?
C#:

```
 pet u= new Pet(){
    animal = "cat",                            
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways:

Without a `Pet` class:

```
var pet = new 
{
    Animal =  "cat",
    Food = new Func<Val,string>((val) => $"X: {val.data.value[0]}")
};

class Val { ... } // We still need to define the input object
```

With the `Pet` class:

```
var pet = new Pet 
{
    Animal =  "cat",
    Food = (val) => $"X: {val.data.value[0]}"
};

class Pet {

    public string? Animal { get; init; }

    public Func<Val, string>? Food { get; init; } // Function that takes in object of type Val and returns a string
}

class Val 
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a C# version of this use of Object Notation. The closest you'd be able to come is an [`anonymous type`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types).
I'm not sure exactly what type you're expecting `val` to be, so I made a quick example with `val` being an `int`:

```csharp
Func<int,string> foodFunc = (int val) => "X:" + val.ToString();
var pet = new { Animal = "cat", Food = foodFunc };
```

If you're using this for more than one or two instances though, I'd suggest making a full [`class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes) for it.
Here's the same example as a class, without the anonymous function:

```csharp
Pet pet = new Pet("cat");
string food = pet.Food(4);

internal sealed class Pet
{
    public string Animal { get; }

    public Pet(string animal)
    {
        Animal = animal;
    }

    public string food(int val) => "X: " + val.ToString();
}
```